# Where should I keep my context instance in asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm building an asp website and using Entity framework as ORM.

Where should I put my entity frame work instance ?

currently in every controller i have a private member that looks like this :

```
MyDBEntities mDbContext = new MyDBEntities();
```

This means that on every request, a new controller is created which in turn creates a new mDbContext . Moreover, I have `mDbContext` in the membership provider (to check if the user is a member) and in the role provider(to check his role) and in some binders(to get some data which the view cant supply), meaning I might create 3-4 connections to the db for every page request?

I'm probably doing something wrong, but what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As for the controllers this is perfectly OK. Many IoC examples with MVC recommend constructor injection of a context into an MVC controller, which is nearly the same.

One context instance in the membership/role providers is not a good idea because they are singletons. Sooner or later the context will get addressed by multiple threads. You should have a context per method call there.

More details here: [What could cause many data access exceptions using EF code first in a custom RoleProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12677975/861716).

Answer (score 0):

put your database logic in a database class (for example a repository).

in that repository, you can have multiple methods (`getallcustomers`, `savecustomer` etc.) which all create a new `MyDBEntities` object, with a `using` statement:

```
using (MyDBEntities mDbContext = new MyDBEntities())
{
   //your db code here

}
```

as i understand creating the `MyDBEntities` object is not more than creating a new connection in ADO.Net so it's a lightweight operation.

you can call the repository methods from your controller.

if you seem to use a method quite often from a controller (ie multiple times per request), you might consider caching.

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question. i know that creating this instance is like creating a new connection.
But creating a new connection is time and resource consuming, i don't want to create 5 connections in every page request. 
i want the asp.net to use the same connection for each session, otherwise i'll have many open connections which in turn will cause the db to stop responding because he has a limited amount of open connections which he can handle.

Comment: as i understood, creating a new connection this way is not time and resource consuming because it uses connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the `Unit Of Work` pattern, a [demo web app here](https://efmvc.codeplex.com/).