# Custom RoleProvider with singleton DbContext possibly conflicting with PerRequest DbContext in MVC3 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, database-connection, dbcontext, roleprovider

I have an MVC3 application using Entity Framework 4.1 and Ninject. It uses a standard Repository pattern which accepts an IUnitOfWork/DbContext (from Ninject) on a PerRequest basis.

The website has worked fine for single-user testing. We recently started doing some concurrent load testing with 2+ users and started getting this error for some requests:

**The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.**

```
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. --->   
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionBusy.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Store.Security.StoreSecurityService.GetUserGroupRoles(String username) in C:\Dev\Store2\Trunk\Store.Security\StoreSecurityService.cs:line 57
at Store.Security.StoreSecurityService.GetRolesForUser(String username) in C:\Dev\Store2\Trunk\Store.Security\StoreSecurityService.cs:line 23
at Store.Security.StoreRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) in C:\Dev\Store2\Trunk\Store.Security\StoreRoleProvider.cs:line 37
at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I am wondering if this issue is caused by having a custom RoleProvider which implements the MVC RoleProvider class, which needs access to a DbContext to make calls to the database.

```
public class StoreRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public IStoreSecurityService StoreSecurityService { get; set; }

    public StoreRoleProvider()
    {
        StoreSecurityService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IStoreSecurityService));
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        return StoreSecurityService.GetRolesForUser(username);
    }
}
```

Originally, we resolved an instance of the IStoreSecurityService which had a DbContext injected into it (PerRequest), but I understand the RoleProvider is only created once at the start of the application and so the DbContext would be disposed of at the end of the request.

I tried a specific instance in the constructor like this:

```
public StoreRoleProvider()
{
   StoreSecurityService = new StoreSecurityService(new DbContext());
}
```

but this produces a similar error.

The linq query throwing the error is not particular difficult...

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    var roles = (from user in _dbContext.Set<User>()
                 join userRole in _dbContext.Set<UserRole>() 
                     on user.Id equals userRole.IserId
                 join role in _dbContext.Set<Role>() 
                     on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                 where user.UserName == username && !userRole.IsDeleted 
                 select role.Name).ToList<string>();
    return roles;
}
```

I don't understand why the connection is changing state so much.

Any ideas would be gratefully appreciated :)

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677975/what-could-cause-many-data-access-exceptions-using-ef-code-first-in-a-custom-rol.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Its the same problem, but the resolution is different to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much testing, I think I've fixed the problem.

For some reason the RoleProvider doesn't like using a Singleton DbContext.

So as a bit of an untidy fix, I have two constructors on StoreSecurityService. One constructor receives the IUnitOfWork (which contains the DbContext) as is resolved using Ninject in the normal way.

The second constructor has no parameters. Internally within the code, everytime a linq query needs a DbContext, it calls directly to ninject to resolve the current IUnitOfWork instance (which is PerRequest). It creates a local variable for this context and then uses it as normal.

Having the DependencyResolver within the class makes it more difficult to unit test, so I may refactor this GetDbContext method out into a separate class to make it more transparent.

```
public class SolvencySecurityService : ISolvencySecurityService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _privateContext;

    private DbContext GetDbContext()
    {
        if (_privateContext != null)
        return _privateContext;

        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
    }

    public StoreSecurityService()
    {

    }

    public StoreSecurityService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _privateContext = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```