# Entity framework with asp.net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5

I have a strange behavior with my EF using repository + unti od work patterns.

the issue is that, when i create a user and assign him a role, a redirection to the destination page, require the a specific role, so in my RoleProvider i override the GetRolesForUser :

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{

    string[] listRoles = unitOfWork.RoleRepository.Find(r => r.Utilisateurs.Any(u => u.Login == username)).ToList().Select(r => r.Nom).ToArray<string>();



    return listRoles;
}
```

at this moment the user in the database is already created but he doesn't appear with his role.

i change my code to this new version :

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    string[] listRoles;

    Utilisateur user = unitOfWork.UtilisateurRepository.Find(u => u.Login == username).FirstOrDefault();

    if (user != null)
        listRoles = user.Roles.Select(r => r.Nom).ToList().ToArray();
    else
    {
        listRoles = new string[1];
        listRoles[0] = "";
    }


    return listRoles;
}
```

for information, i use a unit of work per request.

in both MembershipProvider and RoleProvider class , i use:

```
private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
```

and in my DAl i use a generic repository :

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    internal DVEntities context;
    internal IDbSet<T> dbset;


    public GenericRepository(DVEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbset = context.Set<T>();
    }
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All()
    {
        return dbset.AsQueryable();
    }

    //public IQueryable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> expression)
    public IQueryable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> expression)
    {
        return dbset.Where(expression).AsQueryable();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Attach(entity);
    }

    public void Detach(T entity)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Detach(entity);            
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbset.Attach(entity);
        }
        dbset.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbset.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        //dbset.Add(entityToUpdate);

        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

can anyone explain me the issue please?

thanks.

Comment: I absolutely don't understand your question :( What exactly does not work? What is the result that you expect? Does the second version of `GetRolesForUser` work, but not the first one? Or are they both not working?

Comment: Maybe similar to the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12681527/861716. Try a new `unitOfWork` per call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repository should take an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as parameter, not a `Func<T, bool>`:

```
public IQueryable<T> Find(Expresssion<Func<T, bool>> expression)
```

Then your first version using ...

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    string[] listRoles = unitOfWork.RoleRepository
        .Find(r => r.Utilisateurs.Any(u => u.Login == username))
        .Select(r => r.Nom)
        .ToArray();

    return listRoles;
}
```

... should work.

Comment: it works correctly.
I understand that the use of the expression enforce the data verification on the database ?

Comment: @user1081350: Yes, by using expressions the Linq query will be translated into SQL and executed in the database.